# How do I install the "Beeline" Hive client?

Tags: software-installation, hive

How can I install the hive client `beeline` without having to install all the hive/hadoop ecosystem on my laptop?

I want to use it to query a remote Hive database.

Comment: May I ask where you download Beeline?

Comment: Relevant: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo the wiki doesn't really guide you through the installation of the client.. where can I download it and how do I install it?

Comment: That's the question. I like to know as well. :-)

Comment: @A.B. it looks like you have to download the complete hive to get access to beeline, e.g. http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/hive/hive-2.1.0/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 4):

You can get beeline by installing Hive and Hadoop (Hadoop is a necessary dependency for Hive).

First download Hadoop common from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/ . Unpack and set the variable `HADOOP_HOME` to this location. Example:

```shell
$ wget https://apache.uib.no/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.6/hadoop-3.3.6.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf hadoop-3.3.6.tar.gz
$ export HADOOP_HOME="$(pwd)/hadoop-3.3.6" # You may want set this var in your .bashrc
```

Second, for Hadoop to run, you need to make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set:

```shell
# Find java home:
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep java.home
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64  # Replace with your JAVA_HOME
```

Third, download a *bin* version of Hive from https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html , unpack and then you can run `bin/beeline`. Example:

```shell
$ wget https://apache.uib.no/hive/hive-3.1.3/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf apache-hive-3.1.3-bin.tar.gz
$ cd apache-hive-3.1.3-bin
$ bin/beeline --version
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/ttt/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/ttt/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive 3.1.3
Git git://MacBook-Pro.fios-router.home/Users/ngangam/commit/hive -r 4df4d75bf1e16fe0af75aad0b4179c34c07fc975
Compiled by ngangam on Sun Apr 3 16:58:16 EDT 2022
From source with checksum 5da234766db5dfbe3e92926c9bbab2af
```

Comment: Is that an error on line 4 of the last code block? I presume it shouldn't have the `/` at the start.

Comment: You are right, fixed now (and updated to recent version of hadoop/hive)

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to install beeline/hive. All you have to do is collect the relevant jars from your system and copy them and place them in a single folder.

Suppose, we have a source system where you have beeline and a target system where you want to run beeline.

On the source system collect the relevant jars into one folder. The best way I have found to identify the exact jars involved is to use the jvm option: `-verbose:class`

I.e., you should be able to issue a `java` command that will replicate a typical beeline command invocation on the source system.

Then copy those files into one folder on the target system. `cd` to that folder to make the `-classpath` reference later simple.

I use an HDP 2.5 Hortonworks distro. For me, the following invocation on the target system works:
`java -Xmx1024m -classpath apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:avatica-1.8.0.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:calcite-core-1.2.0.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:calcite-linq4j-1.2.0.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:commons-cli-1.2.jar:commons-codec-1.4.jar:commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:commons-configuration-1.6.jar:commons-lang-2.6.jar:commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:curator-client-2.6.0.jar:curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:derby-10.10.2.0.jar:guava-14.0.1.jar:hadoop-annotations-2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hadoop-auth-2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245-standalone.jar:jce.jar:jline-2.12.jar:jsse.jar:log4j-1.2.16.jar:rt.jar:slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:sunec.jar:sunjce_provider.jar:super-csv-2.2.0.jar:xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar -Dhdp.version=2.5.0.0-1245 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhdp.version=2.5.0.0-1245  -Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/userid -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/userid -Dhadoop.id.str=userid -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=:/home/userid -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/userid/parquet-logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=beeline-log4j.properties -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /home/userid/hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245.jar org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine  -n userid -p pass -u "jdbc:hive2://knox.company.com:8000/;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/tdcprd/hive"`

Some of the parameters are probably not necessary, but I kept them because that is how it is done on the source system. You should use source system's java invocation as a reference pattern.